# Creating a grid on the side of a control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Just recently started WPF and well into the run before I can walk stage.

I have made a custom control that I need for one of my projects, and it looks almost exactly as I want. It currently looks like this:

[image: Currently looks like]

whereas I need to add a scale to the horizontal and vertical sides, with a mark and a number of how many cells we are at, skipping a predefined number which should look roughly like this:

[image: Currently looks like]

The model that provides the data for the control has the data, the size of each cell (and thus the overall size), all the label text, and a step value for the X and Y control.

The control is a grid with the title in the top row, the y title, space for the numbers, the control in the second row and the space for the X control in the next and the title of the x axis in the last.

If I was doing windows forms I would just draw in manually and it would be pretty simple, but I would like to learn this properly.
After a lot of googling, I can't find a way of doing this easily in XAML, so I assume I have to do a custom control on a canvas, or is there an obvious way that my inexperience with WPF is missing?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing out to the box but there is a control you can work off of to get what you need. Investigate modifying the [TickBar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.tickbar(v=vs.110).aspx).

An initial search turned up [How to use string values in place of ticks on WPF Tickbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577574/how-to-use-string-values-in-place-of-ticks-on-wpf-tickbar).

Comment: Thanks for that - worth pursuing. I guess that is where our common language falls down again, I would have never thought to have called them ticks, I was just doing searches for scales and marks!